# Passing xml data to helm chart

Tags: kubernetes, kubernetes-helm

Let's say there is a `config.xml` file outside the chart directory. Can this file be copied to a directory inside the container?

If its inside the chart directory, its pretty easy to use `configMap` as in

```
{{ (tpl (.Files.Glob "myconf/*").AsConfig . ) | indent 2 }}
```

Since the file is outside chart directory its not supported in helm2(although there is some talk of supporting in helm3).

Thought of putting as in

```
key: |
  <tag>abc</tag>
```

Then read in the configMap and put as file.

Is there any elgant way to do it?

Answer (score 1):

Yes. All examples I see until now use this way.